# Finding employment history with weekly snapshot

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table that captures employment status on a monthly basis.
I have a scenario where an employee started off as an intern, went back to school and came back full-time.

Ideally, I would want an output along lines of, which is pretty much a history of his/her employment history.

```
date_hire    date_termination    employee_id    employee_type
2012_01_01   2012_03_01          10002          intern
2012_05_01   null                10002          full-time
```

Data looks like

```
date_snapshot    date_hire    date_termination    employee_id    employee_type
2012_01_01       2012_01_01   null                10002          intern
2012_02_01       2012_01_01   null                10002          intern
2012_03_01       2012_01_01   2012_03_01          10002          intern
2012_04_01       2012_01_01   2012_03_01          10002          intern
2012_05_01       2012_05_01   null                10002          full-time
2012_06_01       2012_05_01   null                10002          full-time
2012_07_01       2012_05_01   null                10002          full-time
......
```

I tried doing this using GROUP BY technique

```
SELECT
    date_hire,
    date_termination,
    employee_id,
    employee_type
FROM
    employees
GROUP BY
    date_hire,
    date_termination,
    employee_id,
    employee_type
```

returns me, note that I have one unwanted record

```
date_hire    date_termination    employee_id    employee_type
2012_01_01   null                10002          intern
2012_01_01   2012_03_01          10002          intern
2012_05_01   null                10002          full-time
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

If we know for sure that employee cannot return to a previous type (e.g. intern-->AWF-->full-time-->AWF) then there is a simple solution:

```
select      date_hire
           ,min (date_termination)  as date_termination
           ,employee_id
           ,employee_type

from        employees e

group by    date_hire
           ,employee_id
           ,employee_type
;
```

Otherwise -

```
select    date_hire
         ,date_termination
         ,employee_id
         ,employee_type

from     (select    e.*
                   ,lead (date_hire)        over (partition by e.employee_id order by date_snapshot) as next_date_hire
                   ,lead (date_termination) over (partition by e.employee_id order by date_snapshot) as next_date_termination
                   ,lead (employee_type)    over (partition by e.employee_id order by date_snapshot) as next_employee_type
                   ,max  (date_snapshot)    over (partition by e.employee_id)                        as max_date_snapshot

          from      employees e
          )

where     date_hire         <> next_date_hire
      or  date_termination  <> next_date_termination
      or  employee_type     <> next_employee_type
      or  date_snapshot     =  max_date_snapshot
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query should also provide your desired output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(date_hire) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id,employee_type) date_hire,
       MIN(date_termination)  OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id,employee_type) date_termination,
      employee_type,employee_id
FROM employees;
```